# Different boost version causing failure in boost/core/ref.hpp due to deleted function

Tags: c++, boost

I have switched my boost version and I am trying to recompile my code but I get the following error:

> /boost/core/ref.hpp:179: error: deleted function ‘void boost::cref(const T&&) [with T = const char*]’

It is for this specific line here:

```
    // find file prefix with matching system type in systemtype attribute
    pugi::xml_named_node_iterator xmniFilePrefix = std::find_if(xmnrFilePrefixes.begin(),xmnrFilePrefixes.end(),
                                    boost::bind(std::equal_to<std::string>(), 
                                                boost::bind(PUMLinux::Functions::ObtainAttributeValue, _1, boost::cref(PUMLinux::Configuration::SYSTEMTYPE.c_str())),
                                                c_strSystemType));
```

Anyone know what I can do to resolve the issue with the new boost I'm using?

Answer (score 1):

You can not do this, boost is exactly correct in doing so. You are taking cref() to the temporary, but cref is nothing more than a fancy wrapping around the pointer.

So you are trying to get an address to the temporary object returned by c_str(), and this is no-no-no.

However, since it seems to be static, unchanged string SYSTEMTYPE, you can get away by completely eliminating `boost::cref` - pass the return value of `c_str()` directly. You might need to change the signature of your `ObtainAttributeValue` to receive pointer.

Comment: But isn't the lifetime of the temporary string in this case the same as the lifetime of the object returned by bind?  I.e. don't both live "until the semi-colon"?  I can understand the deletion of `cref( const T&&)` as a way to prevent `auto b = bind( &SomeMethod, cref( MakeTemporary() ) );` but in this case I think it's actually safe.

Comment: cref doesn't know. The return char* is a temporary, and boost prevents from creating a cref to it. However, the varaible itself is static and not modified, and as such, the buffer char* points to is guaranteed to live as long as the program lives.